# How to define the nodes and elements in ABAQUS input file?

Tags: abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I have edited an ABAQUS input file generated from the maple code written to create a 3D model for analysis. The input file is missing the nodes and element definitions. Can someone give me some example on how to edit the following code to input the model for analysis.

```
*HEADING
Woven Unit Cell
***NODE DEFINITION***
*NODE, NSET=NALL
***ELEMENT DEFINITION***
***MATRIX***
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D8, ELSET=MATRIX
***FIBERS***
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D8, ELSET=FIBER1
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D8, ELSET=FIBER2
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D8, ELSET=FIBER3
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D8, ELSET=FIBER4
*MATERIAL, NAME=MMATRIX
*ELASTIC, TYPE=ISOTROPIC
3.45E+9, 0.35
*MATERIAL, NAME=MFIBER1
*ELASTIC, TYPE=ENGINEERING CONSTANTS
1.72E+11, 4.72E+09, 4.72E+09, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 3.6E+10, 3.6E+10
3.6E+10
*MATERIAL, NAME=MFIBER2
*ELASTIC, TYPE=ENGINEERING CONSTANTS
1.72E+11, 4.72E+09, 4.72E+09, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 3.6E+10, 3.6E+10
3.6E+10
*MATERIAL, NAME=MFIBER3
*ELASTIC, TYPE=ENGINEERING CONSTANTS
1.72E+11, 4.72E+09, 4.72E+09, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 3.6E+10, 3.6E+10
3.6E+10
*MATERIAL, NAME=MFIBER4
*ELASTIC, TYPE=ENGINEERING CONSTANTS
1.72E+11, 4.72E+09, 4.72E+09, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 3.6E+10, 3.6E+10
3.6E+10
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=MATRIX, MATERIAL=MMATRIX
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=FIBER1, MATERIAL=MFIBER1, ORIENTATION=FTRANS
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=FIBER2, MATERIAL=MFIBER2, ORIENTATION=FTRANS
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=FIBER3, MATERIAL=MFIBER3, ORIENTATION=FLONG
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=FIBER4, MATERIAL=MFIBER4, ORIENTATION=FLONG
*ORIENTATION, NAME=FLONG, SYSTEM=RECTANGULAR, DEFINITION=COORDINATES
1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.
*ORIENTATION, NAME=FTRANS, SYSTEM=RECTANGULAR, DEFINITION=COORDINATES
0., 1., 0., -1., 0., 0.
***NODE SETS***
*NSET, NSET=BASE
*NSET, NSET=TOP
*NSET, NSET=XMIN
*NSET, NSET=XMAX
*NSET, NSET=YMIN
*NSET, NSET=YMAX
*STEP, NLGEOM
*STATIC
*RESTART, WRITE, FREQ=1
***BOUNDARY CONDITIONS***
*BOUNDARY
BASE,3,,0.
TOP,3,,0.
XMIN,1,,0.
XMAX,1,,0.001
YMIN,2,,0.
YMAX,2,,0.
***NODE SET DEFINITION***
*ELSET, ELSET=ALLF
FIBER1,FIBER2,FIBER3,FIBER4
*END STEP
```

Answer (score 0):

An ID followed by the coordinates identifies each node.
For one C3D8 element you need at least 8 nodes. For instance:

```
*NODE, NSET=NALL
      1,           1.,           1.,           1.
      2,           1.,           0.,           1.
      3,           1.,           1.,           0.
      4,           1.,           0.,           0.
      5,           0.,           1.,           1.
      6,           0.,           0.,           1.
      7,           0.,           1.,           0.
      8,           0.,           0.,           0.
```

Similarly, each element has an ID and the nodes in the right order.
Each C3D8 element can be created as, for instance:

```
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D8, ELSET=MATRIX
1, 5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 4, 3
```

This scheme may help you.

```
**  8-node     7-----------3
**            /|          /|
**           / |         / |    y
**          5-----------1  |    |
**          |  |        |  |    |
**          |  |        |  |    |
**          |  8--------|--4    0-----> x
**          | /         | /    /
**          |/          |/    /
**          6-----------2    z   origin at node 8
```